# Div font weight need to be bold by code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have Div which i need to make it bold in code behind but my code not working

here is div

```
<div 
         id="dvLock" 
         runat="server" class="col-md-8" 
         style="border-bottom:inherit;" >

 <span ID="DisplyHelpTextLocked" 
        runat="server" 
        visible='<%# (Eval("Parent.BlockReclass").ToString() == "ZL") %>'>

 Click this option to remove. Future authorizations will be allowed effective immediately.

<br /> 
<br />

</span>
    
</div>
```

C# code on page_load:

```
if (User.Id == "B")
{
    dvLock.Style["font-weight"] = "bold";
}
```

But its giving error that null reference found for div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use style.add() method.

It works if the style does not exist, and even if it does, it does not add it again.

Hence, try this:

```
dvLock.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
```

## Edit: In comments, poster notes not working.

So, say this markup:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">


        <div
            id="dvLock"
            runat="server" class="col-md-8"
            style="border-bottom: inherit;">

            <span id="DisplyHelpTextLocked"
                runat="server"
                visible='<%# (Eval("Parent.BlockReclass").ToString() == "ZL") %>'>
                Click this option to remove. Future authorizations will be allowed effective immediately.
                <br />
                <br />
            </span>
        </div>


        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
                Text="Set to bold"
                OnClick="Button1_Click"

    </form>
</body>
```

And code behind for the button is this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dvLock.Style.Add("font-weight", "bold");
    }
```

And the result is thus this:

[image]

Comment: this is also giving error System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Comment: See my edit. I show that my posted code works fine. You don't use [], but .add("some style", "some style value"). Since my posted code works and is 100% tested and verifed as working, then TRY my above posted code and see if it works for you. Since your code is not working, then you have to edit your post, and provide more details, or provide more markup, since my posted code based on YOUR markup works 100% fine, and thus we are not able to re-produce your error or problem.. So, see the edit, try the code - it works as posted.